# calculated field with TKinter

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite, calculated-field

i am using Tkinter. i would like to calculate to total price from price and quantity, but it don't work.

```
    def adding(self):
    if self.validation():
        query = 'INSERT INTO products VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)'
        parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get(), self.price.get() * self.quantity.get() ,self.quantity.get(),self.date.get())
        self.run_query(query,parameters)
        self.message['text']= 'Record {} added'.format (self.name.get())
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} added'.format(self.price.get())
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} added'.format(self.quantity.get())
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} added'.format(self.quantity.get() * self.price.get())
        self.message['text'] = 'Record {} added'.format(self.date.get())

        self.name.delete(0, END)
        self.price.delete(0, END)
        self.quantity.delete(0, END)
        self.date.delete(0, END)
    else:
        self.message['text'] = 'name field or price is empty'
        self.viewing_records()
```

i got the fellowing error:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1550, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "C:/Users/me/PycharmProjects/crawler/db.py", line 78, in adding
>       parameters = (self.name.get(), self.price.get(), self.price.get() * self.quantity.get() ,self.quantity.get(),self.date.get())
>   TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

can you help me for this, this data is stored in sqlite3 table

Comment: When you call `get()` on an entry widget, you will get back a string rather than a number.

Comment: You will need to convert the string that `get()` has returned to an integer using `int()`. You will also need to make sure that the string value that `get()` is returning is always a number or else `int()` will cause an error.

Comment: what you have here is not producing error in your post

Answer (score 0):

When you use `get()` it will always return a string. Because of this you will need to convert that string into a number in order to perform any math operations. We can do this with the use of `int()` or `float()`. `Int()` will only work on whole numbers where `float()` will work on number that contain a decimal point or whole numbers.

One way we can deal with possible errors is to use the `try/except` method.
We first tell python to try to do the math because we are expecting a number however if we get something other than a number we then can produce an error message.

See the below code example of multiplying a number by itself to get a result.

```
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()

my_entry = tk.Entry(root)
my_entry.pack()
my_label = tk.Label(root, text="Results:")
my_label.pack()

def do_math():
    try:
        x = int(my_entry.get())
        my_label.config(text="Results: {}".format(x * x))

    except:
        my_label.config(text="Results: Error: Blank or non int provided")

btn = tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command=do_math)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

There are other methods to deal with impute values such as forcing the entry field to only accept numbers and decimal points by using a validation function. We could create a complex function to check if the value is an integer or a float as well before performing any math. Most of this is more than we need for a simple math problem like this though.